# AWK: filtering of the lines based on the column similarity

Tags: csv, awk

I am dealing with the post-processing of multi-column CSV arranged in fixed format:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 12, -5.6500
2, 10, -5.5100
3, 14, -5.3500
4, 17, -5.3400
5, 8, -5.3000
6, 1, -5.1800
7, 12, -5.1700
8, 7, -5.1500
9, 3, -5.1100
10, 6, -5.0200
11, 2, -5.0100
12, 2, -4.9500
13, 1, -4.9000
14, 14, -4.8400
15, 4, -4.8300
16, 2, -4.8300
17, 6, -4.7700
18, 7, -4.7600
19, 3, -4.7200
20, 6, -4.7100
```

I need to reduce the number of the lines in this data focusing i) on the search of the line with the highest number in the second column, pop(MAX); ii) while keeping in the output the lines with the POP column > or = 0.6*pop(MAX); and iii) keep always the first line (with the ID 1). I've used the following AWK expression for the practical realisation:

```
awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) max=$2; next} FNR == 2 || $2 > (.6 * max)' input.csv input.csv > output.csv
```

that gives me the following output.csv

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 12, -5.6500
3, 14, -5.3500
4, 17, -5.3400
7, 12, -5.1700
14, 14, -4.8400
```

How could I modify my AWK expression to include additionally the next line after POP MAX if it matches another condition with the lower persentatage similarity to pop max: POP  > or = 0.4*pop(MAX),
so the output should consist additional string if its POP column fit the rule (I added # coments to clarify the selection of each line):

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 12, -5.6500 # the first line is always taken 
3, 14, -5.3500 # POP  > or = 0.6*pop(MAX)
4, 17, -5.3400 # it is POP MAX
5, 8, -5.3000  # it is the string next to pop max: POP  > or = 0.4*pop(MAX)
7, 12, -5.1700 # POP  > or = 0.6*pop(MAX)
14, 14, -4.840 # POP  > or = 0.6*pop(MAX)
```

Comment: Suggestion (not tried): init a "flag" variable to 0. Set flag = 1 if condition is met, and check for flag presence when you output lines. Then clear flag again inside. This way you can temporarily for 1 line overrule the usual condition.

Comment: need an example of AWK code with the practical realisation to understand how it could work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR+1} next} FNR <= 2 || FNR == n || $2 > (.6 * max)' input.csv input.csv

ID, POP, dG
1, 12, -5.6500
3, 14, -5.3500
4, 17, -5.3400
5, 8, -5.3000
7, 12, -5.1700
14, 14, -4.8400
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -F ', ' '
NR == 1 {next}
FNR == NR {
   if (max < $2) {
      max = $2
      n = FNR+1
   }
   next
}
FNR <= 2 || FNR == n || $2 > (.6 * max)
' input.csv{,}
```

- `input.csv{,}` is brace expansion in bash that just repeats string twice to make it `input.csv input.csv`

Comment: sorry what is input.csv{,}?I'vetried simple imput.csv > putput.csv but it did not work. could you also additionally shown an example how to transform it to the one liner? Thanksss!!

Comment: thank you! one question where I could modify the second cut-off applied for the selection of the second line ? assuming that $2 > (.6 * max) is the cut-off applied for all lines, If I understand correclty

Comment: yep exactly I mean that could we introduce the same (in additon to what we already have) specifictly for the second line with lower cut-off like $2 > (.4 * max) ? For the case not to take the line after pop(MAX) if it has very low population :-)

Comment: If you want an additional condition for `FNR==n` then use `FNR <= 2 || (FNR == n && $2 > (.4*max)) || $2 > (.6 * max)`

Comment: yes this was my question to customize it abit :-) now the script always take the line next to pop max, while I need to take it if it match the condition $2 > (.4 * max) so in fact the script should contain 2 conditions: one for the second line, and another for all lines exept it :-)

Comment: Thank you! so the entere one-liner would became: awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR+1} next} FNR <= 2 || (FNR == n && $2 > (.4*max)) || $2 > (.7 * max)' input{,} > output. right ??

Comment: a final épisode from the epic trilogy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987158/awk-filtering-of-the-data-based-on-two-column-information