# AWK: filtering of the data based on TWO column information

Tags: csv, awk

I am working on post-processing of multi-column CSV arranged in multi-column format:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 10, -5.6200
2, 4, -5.4900
3, 1, -5.3000
4, 4, -5.1600
5, 4, -4.8800
6, 3, -4.7600
7, 2, -4.4900
8, 5, -4.4500
9, 2, -4.4400
10, 8, -4.1400
11, 1, -4.1200
12, 2, -4.0900
13, 5, -4.0100
14, 1, -3.9500
15, 3, -3.9200
16, 10, -3.8800
17, 1, -3.8700
18, 3, -3.8300
19, 1, -3.8200
20, 3, -3.8000
```

Previously I have used the following AWK sollution to process the inout log two times, detect pop(MAX) and save linnes which matched $2 > (.8 * max)':

```
awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (max < $2) {max=$2; n=FNR+1} next} FNR <= 2 || (FNR == n && $2 > (.4*max)) || $2 > (.8 * max)' input.csv{,} > output.csv
```

that could reduce the input log keeping just two linnes with highest POP:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 10, -5.6200
16, 10, -3.8800
```

Now I need to change the search algorithm taking into account the both 2nd (POP) and 3rd(dG) columns: i) always taking the first line as the reference, which always has most negative number in the 3rd column (dG); ii) finding the line which has biggest number in the second column, pop(MAX);
iii) taking all linnes between (i) and (ii) that will match the following rule applied for the BOTH columns:
a) line should have (negative) number in 3rd column, matching following the rule: $1 > (.5 * $1(min))', where  $1(min) is the number (dG) of the first line (always most negative)
b)  additionally line should match the old rule for the second column with decreased threshold : $2 = or > (.5 * max)', where max is the pop(MAX)

So an expecting output should be

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 10, -5.6200.  # this is the first line with most negative dG
8, 5, -4.4500   # this has POP (5) and dG (-4.4500) matching the both rules
10, 8, -4.1400. # this has POP (8) and dG (-4.1400) matching the both rules    
16, 10, -3.8800  # this is pop max, with higher POP
```

#### ADDED 8-04:

For the case if the first line has with very low POP (which does not match the rule $2 >= (.5 * maxPop)

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 5, -5.5600
2, 7, -5.3300
3, 7, -5.1900
4, 1, -4.6800
5, 1, -4.5800
6, 5, -4.5600
7, 3, -4.4700
8, 4, -4.4300
9, 9, -4.4200
10, 4, -4.4200
11, 2, -4.3800
12, 4, -4.3400
13, 25, -4.3000
14, 6, -4.2900
15, 8, -4.2600
16, 3, -4.2300
17, 1, -4.1800
18, 3, -4.1300
19, 1, -4.1300
20, 1, -4.1200
21, 27, -4.0800
22, 2, -4.0300
```

the output should not contain the first line either while still using its value from dG column as the reference for the second condition ($3 <= (.5 * minD), which should be applied for the selection of other linnes in the output:

```
13, 25, -4.3000
21, 27, -4.0800
```

Comment: But `POP(5)` does not meet this condition `$2 > (.5 * maxPop)` so how come it is in output?

Comment: ops it should be actually$2 >= (.5 * maxPop) # equal or bigger

Comment: ok then `13, 5, -4.0100` should also be in output?

Comment: correct since it match the rule for the both columns. I am going to edit it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this `awk` solution:

```sh
awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR <= 2 || ($2 >= (.5 * maxP) && $3 <= (.5 * minD))' file{,}

ID, POP, dG
1, 10, -5.6200
8, 5, -4.4500
10, 8, -4.1400
13, 5, -4.0100
16, 10, -3.8800
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk -F ', ' '
NR == 1 {next}                   # skip 1st record 1st time
FNR == NR {
   if (maxP < $2)                # compute max(POP)
      maxP = $2
   if (minD == "" || minD > $3)  # compute min(dG)
      minD = $3
   next
}
# print if 1st 2 lines OR "$2 >= .5 * max(POP) && $3 <= .5 * min(dG)"
FNR <= 2 || ($2 >= (.5 * maxP) && $3 <= (.5 * minD))
' file{,}
```

Comment: I am going to test it now for several CSV inputs. Looks very nice and correct for the condition for the third column, $3 <= (.5 * minD)) since we are dealing with the negative numbers, meaning that I made error also in the first message, right ??

Comment: it works! just one question: I noticed that while increasing selection threshold for the third column (dG) <= (.7 * minD)) somethimes the line with pop MAX is not included in output.csv (since it does not match anymore the threshold value). Is it possible to make the same for the first line as well (for the case if it does not match the threshold on the second POP column)? This should not to include the first line in the output if its POP is very low compared to POP MAX...

Comment: I mean to apply the filter with the $2 >= (.5 * maxP) on the first line as well (which is used always to calculate minD), while still using its value from dG column as the reference applied for the selection of the other columns in the output. I've just added an example in the bottom of my first post!

Comment: oh that's easy. You can do: `awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR == 1 || ($2 >= (.5 * maxP) && $3 <= (.5 * minD))' file{,}`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much again! Cheers,

Comment: sorry for the additional question: I've found small issue with the last version (which skip the first line) indicated in the comment. Sometimes it produces nothing, while using high cut-offs (0.8), e.g. awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR == 1 || ($2 >= (.8 * maxP) && $3 <= (.8 * minD))' file{,}         It means that there were no linnes which could fill the both conditions at the same time. Is it possible for that case (only if there are not lines to write in the output) always take the line number 1 to the output ?

Comment: ok try this: `awk -F ', ' 'NR == 1 {next} FNR==NR {if (maxP < $2) maxP=$2; if (minD=="" || minD > $3) minD=$3; next} FNR==2{p=$0} FNR == 1 || ($2 >= (.8 * maxP) && $3 <= (.8 * minD)) {++c; print} END {if (c==1) print p}' file{,}`

Comment: Amazing! can't beelive that it's possible :o! thank you very much again!!

Comment: this might be more complicated but also requires an elegant AWK sollution : >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67089862/awk-simple-math-operations-on-multi-column-data-with-subsequent-data-convertion