# AWK: simple math operations on multi-column data with subsequent data conversion

Tags: bash, awk

As a part of my Bash routine, I am dealing with the directory consisted of many folders, with the following naming patters:

```
1000_cne_lig1, 1000_cne_lig2, 1000_cne_lig3, 1000_cne_lig4, 1000_cne_lig5  ... 1000_cne_ligN
2000_cne_lig1, 2000_cne_lig2, 2000_cne_lig3, 2000_cne_lig4, 2000_cne_lig5  ... 2000_cne_ligN
3000_cne_lig1, 3000_cne_lig2, 3000_cne_lig3, 4000_cne_lig4, 5000_cne_lig5  ... 3000_cne_ligN
7000_cne_lig1, 7000_cne_lig2, 7000_cne_lig3, 7000_cne_lig4, 7000_cne_lig5  ... 4000_cne_ligN
...
xxxx_cne_lig1, xxxx_cne_lig2, xxxx_cne_lig3, xxxx_cne_lig4, xxxx_cne_lig5  ... xxxx_cne_ligN
```

Note, that all of the folders can be grouped into X categories (1000,2000 ... xxxx) according to the name of the system, which is defined by the pattern occured before the first slash "_" in the name of each folder.
Inside each of the folder there is a CSV file contained data arranged in multi-line format:

```
ID, POP, dG
1, 40, -5.7600
2, 2, -5.4000
3, 8, -5.3300
```

I need to iteratively loop over the folders belonged to distinct system (e.g. for 5 folders of 1000, then for 5 folders of 2000 etc) and detect the CSV file. Then I need to carry out some simple math operations on each of the CSV log (for particular system): calculate the mean for the negative numbers (in third column of the CSV) and save it in a new file containing the name of the system (e.g. 1000.csv) in one line containing: the name of the particular folder, the mean value. For example for system 1000, the 1000.csv should be:

```
# system 1000; dG(mean)
lig1: -5.555
lig2: -6.003
lig3: -3.031
lig4: -3.222
lig5: -10.300
ligN: -NN.NNN
```

Note, I removed 1000_cne_ in the each of the line (name of the original file) but add it to the head of the CSV.

Finally for X systems, the script should produce X new CSV filles (1000.csv, 2000.csv, XXXX.csv etc) contained N lines according to the number of the folders.

Here is the practical realisation of the bash routine, which already classify the folders and then should be completed by AWK which will do all math and transfer of the computed mean values to new CSV:

```
#!/bin/bash
home=$PWD
# folder with the folders to analyse
storage="${home}"/results
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# pattern to recognize csv file for analysis
csv_pattern='*_filt3b.csv'



# this will iteratively do something on the group of the folders belonged to one syst
for folder in "${storage}"/*; do
# this is the name of each folder
folder_name=$(basename "$folder")
# detect the name of the system (X) determined by 4 characters near the first _ >> this is the name of output.csv
syst_name=$(basename "$folder" | cut -d'_' -f 1)
# detect the name of the sample (N) the last entry after the last _ >> the name of the lines in new CSV
sample_name=$(basename "$folder" | cut -d'_' -f 3)
pushd ${folder}
# apply AWK on each CSV to calculate MEAN and store it in new output.csv :
    awk 'FNR==1 {
   if (n)
      mean[suffix] = s/n
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s=n=0
}
FNR > 1 {
   s+=$3
   ++n
}
END {
   mean[suffix] = s/n
   print "# system", prefix, "; dG(mean)"
   for (i in mean)
      print i ":", mean[i]
}' "${folder}"/*filt3b.csv >> ${rescore}/${syst_name}.csv  
    popd
done
```

This gives me the following output.csv (for ten processed CSV filles of the 1000 system):

```
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -6.44
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -4.59
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -4.96
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -5.17
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -4.73
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -5.04
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -6.625
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -2
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -5.34
# system /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys ; dG(mean)
filt3b.csv: -8.14
```

Indicating that there is some mismatch between BASH and AWK parts: in the output filt3b.csv should be replaced by the part of the name (like lig1 etc) of the FOLDER contained this filt3b.csv. Also the path /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys should not be present but rather replaced by the name of the system (like 1000, occured always at the bottom line of the final output). Finally the numbers of mean values should be provided in the -X.XX format, like -4.59 (not -X or -X.XXX)

Updated: find a possibility to fix a problem with the header of output.csv, via intdoducing it by ECHO before AWK processing within the same script:

```
home=$PWD
# folder with the results
storage="${home}"/results
tmp="${home}"/tmp
rescore="${home}"/rescore

# csv for rescoring
csv_pattern='*_filt3b.csv'
    
if [ -d "${rescore}" ]; then
  rm -rf "${rescore}"
  mkdir "${rescore}"
  else
  mkdir "${rescore}"
fi


for folder in "${storage}"/*; do
# this is the name of each folder
folder_name=$(basename "$folder")
# detect the name of the system (X) determined by 4 characters near the first _ >> this is the name of output.csv
syst_name=$(basename "$folder" | cut -d'_' -f 1)
# detect the name of the sample (N) the last entry after the last _ >> the name of the lines in new CSV
sample_name=$(basename "$folder" | cut -d'_' -f 3)
pushd $folder
# a simple example of output format w/o calculations
if [ ! -f ${rescore}/${syst_name}.csv ]; then
# add the header to the CSV contained name of the system
echo "${syst_name}: dG(rescored)" > ${rescore}/${syst_name}.csv
fi
# apply AWK on each CSV to calculate mean for the numbers in third column 
awk 'FNR==1 {
   if (n)
      mean[suffix] = s/n
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s=n=0
}
FNR > 1 {
   s+=$3
   ++n
}
END {
   mean[suffix] = s/n
   #print "# system", prefix, "; dG(mean)"
   for (i in mean)
      print i ":", mean[i]
}' ${folder}/${csv_pattern} >> ${rescore}/${syst_name}.csv
popd
done
```

which gives 1000.csv for 10 folders like 1000_cne_ligN:

```
1000: dG(rescored)
filt3b.csv: -6.3825
filt3b.csv: -4.455
filt3b.csv: -5.28
filt3b.csv: -5.76
filt3b.csv: -5.52
filt3b.csv: -3.92
filt3b.csv: -7.505
filt3b.csv: -1.8
filt3b.csv: -5.79
filt3b.csv: -5.61
```

Comment: So you are stuck in writing the awk-program? I don't see a real question in your "question".

Comment: yes, indeed it was due to the stuck with awk, since I substituted it by simple echo example showing what my algorithm normally should do.

Comment: So, the whole question relates to awk, as the bash part is irrelevant. In this case, I suggest that you tag your question awk only, and define what kind of calculation you want to do, and post the awk program you have got so far.

Comment: Yes, indeed, bash part were used to demonstrate how I manage the folders in the directory. If its tricky to understand the aim of AWK, I will create another topic focusing only on AWK parts. However it's important to consider ALL of the folders since I do calculation for each of them independently but store the output in the same output.csv which contain the number of the linnes equal to number of the folders for particular system (like 1000, 2000 etc)

Comment: Silly question: If you find using of awk tricky (it is not a language of everyone's taste), why don't you use a different one you feel more comfortable in?

Comment: I've updated the first topic indicating where is the actually problem since its related to the interaction between AWK and BASH in that case. Why AWK? Funcitonally I found it super fast with that kind of taks integrated inside of bash loops etc ...

Comment: Please don't squeeze the whole awk program into a single line; it is difficult to read. Use several lines and format it properly. With an awk program of that complexity, I would put it into a separate file anyway.

Comment: IT is actually AWK sollution given in the answer to this topic, I've just modified my post. It is important to keep it inside bash script in my case :-)

Comment: You can still format it into several lines for readability. The answer also contains a nicely formatted version. If it is exactly the solution in the answer, it means that you don't have any question open and you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this single `awk` script for this which is POSIX compliant as well:

```sh
awk 'FNR==1 {if (n) mean[suffix] = s/n; prefix=suffix=FILENAME; sub(/_.*/, "", prefix); sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix); s=n=0} FNR > 1 {s+=$3; ++n} END {mean[suffix] = s/n; print "# system", prefix, "; dG(mean)"; for (i in mean) print i ":", mean[i]}' 1000_*

# system 1000 ; dG(mean)
lig1: -5.49667
lig2: -6.76333
```

---

Based on your edited question here is full shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
home="$PWD"
# folder with the outputs
rescore="${home}"/rescore 
# folder with the folders to analyse
cd "${home}"/results
# pattern to recognize csv file for analysis
csv_pattern='*_filt3b.csv'

while read -r d; do
awk '
FNR==1 {
   if (n)
      mean[suffix] = s/n
   prefix=suffix=FILENAME
   sub(/_.*/, "", prefix)
   sub(/\/[^\/]+$/, "", suffix)
   sub(/^.*_/, "", suffix)
   s=n=0
}
FNR > 1 {
   s += $3
   ++n
}
END {
   mean[suffix] = s/n
   print "# system", prefix, "; dG(mean)"
   for (i in mean)
      printf "%s: %.2f\n", i, mean[i]
}' "${d}_"*/$csv_pattern | sort > "$rescore/"${d%%_*}".csv"
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d -name '*_*_*' | awk -F '[_/]' '!seen[$2]++ {print $2}')
```

Comment: please note that all input folders are well located in the"${storage}" and the output should be saved in ${output} , where ${syst_name}. is always corresponded to the current system name which is being looped. Finally *filt3b.csv is the bash pattern to recognize csv file for which mean should be calculated ( ITS always INSIDE THE DIRECTORY ${syst_name}* )

Comment: I just got something while applying your AWK code using the following input/output   AWK ... "${folder}"/*filt3b.csv >> ${rescore}/${syst_name}.csv , there is only an issue in the name of the CSV since I need to provide the name of the FOLDER instead in the output.csv. I am going to edit my first post to see an example of your output

Comment: correct, inside storage/ there are many subdirectories, inside of which CSV filles are located ( I'd indicated it in my post), like storage/1000_cne_lig1/*filt3b.csv etc. Each subdirectory consist only one *filt3b.csv. Actually your script works very well inside my bash loop, just a problem in the final output.csv ( i indicated also in my first topic) with the names of the (lig1, lig2 etc) which should be taken from the name of the FOLDER (which contain CSV) not the name of CSV itself.

Comment: $folder is a subdirectory inside $storage. so it may be "${storage}"/1000_cne_lig1/ etc. Inside each $folder there is CSV file from which mean value is calculated (it works well now). Finally from the folder name of the system is taken (it is 1000, 2000, XXXX) as well as the name of the sample to the final log (it is lig1, lig2, ligN)

Comment: It gives: /Users/gleb/Desktop/scripts/analys_clusters/results/N000_cne_lig800/*_filt3b.csv    NOTE: analysis_clusters is the FOLDER with my script etc  ${csv_pattern} was created just to match CSV file inside the folder (in the case if I change its name for instance)...

Comment: I've edited my first post (the end ) with the example ...

Comment: ops sorry, just edited the script in the first topic. It is actually csv_pattern='*_filt3b.csv'

Comment: I mean it would be the same if I applied your AWK script on "${folder}"/*filt3b.csv ,suposing that only one CSV file exists in each folder !  I've just put the second version of my full bash routine to the first topic. The only issue is in the first row of the columns added to the output.csv, which contain always only the part of the name of the processed CSV (for which mean was calculated), while I need rather to indicate there a part of the name of the FOLDER (lig1, lig2 etc) contained this CSV...

Comment: ok check my updated answer. Remember this is running from `"${home}"/results` directory as I have used a `cd "${home}"/results`

Comment: Thank you very much! can't believe that it could been achived! just 2 minor question: 1 ) is it possible to set the format of the numbers in the second column (mean values) of new csv filles as - X.XX (it can be now like -2 or -2.1 etc)? 2) is it possible to sort the lines in these output.csv based on the numbers in the first column (lig1, lig2, lig3, lig4, lig5 etc)? Usually I pipe AWK to | sort -k1.4,1 but in that case it have not worked...

Comment: I am comming back with the question about small addition to your AWK code, which works perfectly well (i've just tested on 3000 CSVs!). Could you suggest small modification that would add the 3rd column to the output CSV contained rmsd of the initial data (dG), which was used to calculate MEAN? Normally knowing MEAN it should be expressed like rmsd=$(awk -v mean=$mean '{++n;sum+=($NF-mean)^2} END{if(n) printf "%.2f", sqrt(sum/n)}' "initial_input.csv). May you modify please your answer demonstrating how it could be integrated to your AWK code, adding the 3rd column to the output? Many thanks !

Comment: May I request a new question as this is already a fairly complex bash+awk script. Please clarify requirements in questions with sample data so that we can help you quickly.

Comment: anubhara, I've created my topic in Code Review since it's related mostly to the improvement of the writted algorithm >> https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/260466/bash-awk-workflow-operating-on-multi-column-files        would be very appreciate your help! Cheers